# Difference between using fork/execvp and system call

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

What is the difference between using system() to execute a binary and using the combination of fork/execvp.

Is there any security/portablility/performance difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

System also uses a `fork`/`exec`... combination. If you do `fork`/`exec` yourself you can execute parallel to your running process, while `system` is blocking (includes the `wait`). 
Also `system` executes the command not direct, but via a shell (which makes problems with setuid bit) and `system` blocks/ignores certain signals (SIGINT, SIGCHILD, SIGQUIT).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `system()` runs the command through a shell, while `exec()` runs the command directly. Of course, introducing a shell opens up for bugs and exploits.

Edit: of course, [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) provides more detail.

Comment: "introducing a shell opens up for bugs and exploits" - Only if you allow a person to type the commands.  If your application generates the text of the shell command, there's no possibility of an exploit.

Comment: One possibility is if user changes some shell variables before your code is executed. There is a possibility of exploit, but not sure how generic it is.

Comment: You also have path/linker tricks. [Breaking the links: Exploiting the linker](http://www.nth-dimension.org.uk/pub/BTL.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

`system()` will `fork()`/`exec()` the shell, and then shell will `fork()`/`exec()` the program you want to launch.

So `system()` is twice as heavy as `fork()`/`exec()`

Answer (score 3):

system() works on Windows but fork() doesn't.

Unless you use a compatibility layer such as Cygwin, but even then a fork can be very expensive.

Comment: @Nathan, The question mentions portability differences, which this is.

Comment: I have a question on the issue of expense, How is fork more expensive than system. System too forks a process, instead it forks two processes.

Comment: @foo: fork does not really exist on windows. cygwin emulates it.  See http://www.cygwin.com/faq/faq.api.html#faq.api.fork

Answer (score 2):

there's also popen(), which is like system(), but allows to read child's output and provide input