# c++ system() orphan & zombie processes

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a little application, let's call it "launch.exe".  It is a c++ appl.

What I do in it is I call system() 3 times to launch 3 other applications.  let's call these A, B, and C.

**problem #1**
A, B, and C are GUI apps and "launch.exe" is not able to progress until A exits.  Then it is stuck again until B exits.  Then stuck again until C exits.  I would like lauch.exe to be able to progress while the applications I have opened remain open.

**Problem #2**
Assuming that I am able to figure out a solution to problem #1, after A, B, and C are launched, I don't want "launch.exe" to stay open.  I want launch.exe to close and I want A, B, and C to remain running.

Here is a scenario for you.  Lets us say "launch.exe" only starts one application (let us call it A).  Then, after A is started, if i close "launch.exe", A remains open.

OK...this is what I want but what just happened?  Is A an orphan now? And if so, is this a problem?

And what if I closed A before I exited launch.exe?  On the surface it seems OK, but what does it return to?  If I launched an exe in cmd shell, it would return to that, but since I did it from a system() call in a c++ appl, does it return to my lauch.exe or does it become a zombie?

NOTES:
Why am I useing system()?
--Cause I need something that is Windows/Linux compatible.
--Cause I need to elevate privileges to admin level for some of the applications being launched.
--**I should add that it is vital that A, B, and C be totally independent (for security reasons they should not share the same memory space or anything else).**
--Last, some of the apps, B, and C are multi-threaded (I state this because I have read that some functions do not spawn multi-threaded applications properly.  I'm not clear on reasons why.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `spawn` instead, this won't block the launcher until the child exits.

Or, since you're already using Qt, use `QProcess`.

---

There is no portable way to spawn a subprocess as a different user, but the Windows-specific way is [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431.aspx).

Comment: The problem with QProcess is that I am not able to elevate user rights for applications that need to run with admin privileges.

Comment: @user440297: How are you causing elevation now?  On Linux, you need to use `gsudo` or similar, on Windows, a manifest.

Comment: I also don't see how to elevate privileges with spawn.  To answer your question, I check if sys is Linux or Win and then use appropriate one-liner console command equivalent with system() to lauch app with elevate priv. (in Windows runas...then user..then app and arguments).

Comment: @user440297: Are you saying that `runas` doesn't work with `spawn`?  Are you passing a password to `runas` or letting it prompt?

Comment: Well, the things is that runas does not take password as parameter.  With system this is not a prob because &&.  Thus with spawn I just don't see this being possible.  The user should not have to manually enter a pass, the c++ application should do all that.

Comment: @user440297: I'm not quite sure how `&&` plays into the presence of a password.  But if you're relying on shell features like pipes, you can spawn the shell, something along the lines of `spawn("cmd.exe /c echo Password | runas /user:God whatever")`

Comment: That won't work as "|" doesn't chain console commands instead it only dumps stdout of previous app to the stdin of an application that follows. You can't sript with "|", it has a very limited use. The password is prompted for AFTER the runas command completes.  Even if that was not so, runas does not take password via its stdin. I'd need a way to maintain a session hold on the cmd and provide the password for the password prompt.  Of course this needs to be a controlled procedure, it needs to be after pass is prompted for and not before.

Comment: With system, not only can I chain commands I can ensure previous one executed. Problem is it freezes until child returns.

Comment: @user440297: With `system` nothing special happens.  `system` just passes the command to the shell.  You can do the same with `spawn` by calling the shell.

Comment: Well if you can get this to work you'd be the first that got it on the net cuz I've been searching all day and all i see is people being unable to do this, no one to date has been able to show working c++ code for this (as far as I can tell). I tried so many things, you may think it will work but when you try it...

Comment: @user440297: You haven't shown how you're using `&&` with `system`, so I can't provide an equivalent or perform any testing.

Comment: @Ben Voigt. && doesn't work for this purpose, it turns out.  it was my mistake to assume that it would based on my previous use of && with system.  I just tested it with runas and it doesn't work. Password is prompted for. Further, even directly in cmd console, "|" and "< pass.txt" tricks don't work with runas.

Comment: @user440927: Ok, that sounds like a new problem "How do I provide a password to `runas.exe`?" (and a question for superuser).  Since you're writing C++ code though, you can call [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431.aspx).  All portability goes out the window at this point, you'll need one "run elevated" function for Windows and a different one for Linux, but it will work.

Comment: @Ben Voigt. Thanks for sticking with the thread.  Yes, it is this combination of requirements that is the cause of the headaches.  Since all info shall reside in the compiled c++ *.exe file, end-users do not need to be prompted or burdened with any  questions.  The password will be in the c++ appl.  I thought of OS specific functions, just wished there was a Linux/Win/Mac compatible way.  I suppose I was dreaming. Have a Linux equivalent function you can recommend?

Comment: @user440927: Well, you can always write Linux, Win, Mac versions with the same signature, then contribute them to the `QProcess` source code.

Comment: @Ben Voight. Not sure I can find an equivellent function in Linux for CreateProcessWithLogonW.

Comment: @user440297: I suspect on Linux you could build a new command consisting of `"su"` (plus options) and the original command, and thus get the same signature.

Comment: Maybe, I'll have to test it. Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that if you store passwords in your exe anyone with a text editor might be able to retrieve the string and probably elevate themselves? (Unless you have already thought about this and are taking steps against this.)

Comment: @RedX7, I don't think that anyone with a text editor can read a compiled c++ executable and extract the password.  It is not a vbs script (in fact I can do this with a vbs script easy as I have in the past), but I am avoiding scripting for this very reason. Also, realistically, a key-logger is much more likely to be used to capture the password.  If you know some full proof security measure, that would be of interest.

Comment: @user440297: @RedX7 is absolutely correct.  Although the *code* portions of the executable are binary (and not indecipherable either, they can be disassembled), the *strings* are simple text and can be seen with a text editor, or the `strings` tool.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you start your A B C processes with ampersand "&" appended to command parameters

```
std::system ("ProcessA&");
std::system ("ProcessB&");
std::system ("ProcessC&");
```

This way your launcher will not wait for these processes to exit.

Then exit your launcher with `QApplication::exit` or `QApplication::quit`

Read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304784/difference-between-using-fork-execvp-and-system-call) to see the difference between fork/execvp and system().